# How to clear the data in excel from a selected row and column to the end of the excel?

Tags: python, openpyxl

[Excel with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD8vS.png)
I'm trying to clear the data from the excel using python openpyxl. The data in the excel is dynamic. So, I don't know number of rows and columns. I need to delete the data from specific row and column example from cell B2 to the end of the excel means row 1 and column A should not be edited. I should be able to give any index position in python and clear data till end.

```
def del_excel_template1(file,start_col):
    file = "Sample.xlsx"
    wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
    l = sheet_obj.max_column
    start_col = 2
    for i in range (start_col,l+1):
        sheet_obj.delete_cols(start_col)
    wb_obj.save("Sample.xlsx")
```

Comment: It would be appreciated if you upvote/accept the answers if the answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to iterate through the dynamic range and clear the cells individually:

```
  # iterate through excel and delete data
  for i in range(row_start_range, sheet_obj.max_row+1):
     for j in range(col_start_range, sheet_obj.max_column+1):
        cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row=i, column=j)
        cell_obj.value = None
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be faster to delete the whole rows using openpyxl delete_rows and just clear the cells in the row you want to keep some of.
Note, you should set cell values to None to clear the value, not "".

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

file = 'Sample.xlsx'
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

start_cell = 'B2'

sc = sheet_obj[start_cell]
### Create range for the deletion on the start_cell row
row_cells = f'{start_cell}:{get_column_letter(sheet_obj.max_column)}{sc.column}'

### Set all cells value from start_cell in that row to None
for cell in sheet_obj[row_cells][0]:
    cell.value = None

### Delete all rows from next after start cell to sheet max row
sheet_obj.delete_rows(sc.row+1, amount=sheet_obj.max_row-sc.row)

wb_obj.save('Sample_out.xlsx')
```